# Issue with responsive view on Mobile

Tags: magento

I am not sure if i am asking the question in the right place, but from many days i have been facing an issue with my Magento theme and tried fixing it by editing the layout. but i am not able to get it right for my product page on the responsive side.

The product page hides the Add to cart option behind the header when browsed from mobile or Tablets.

On web it looks like it is working absolutely fine. Is there anyone who can guide me on where to look into for fixing the issue.

www.omegakart.com is the website that i am trying to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking your site.

the question's answer is css reason.

hide `div class='slider'` in css

(or add class hidden-xs if you use bootstrap in your site )

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply. I tried fixing it i am not sure what i did but the Images have falled in place but the 'product-shop' part is still in the wrong place. you can see it in the responsive view it just goes outside the window.http://www.omegakart.com/apparels/women/clothing/dresses-skirts/siya-parineeti-2002.html